# Lexical richness as Shannon's Entropy; Python

Tags: python, string, nlp, entropy, linguistics

The Entropy formula for lexical richness is

[image]

The probability p-ith is calculated by dividing V-ith by N, where N is the total number of tokens in the text and V-ith is the number of times a specific type occurs (at least that's my understanding).

So, if i have a string `the, the, the, a, a, over, love, one, tree`
there are 9 `tokens`, but only 6 `types`.

`V-'theth'` (from what I understand) would be `3` and therefore `p-'theth'` would be calculated as `3/9 = 0.33`. `V-'ath'` would then be `0.22`, and so on. `H` in this instance would be `-100*((0.33*log0.33 + 0.22*log0.22 + 0.11*log0.11 + 0.11*log0.11 + 0.11*log0.11+ 0.11*log0.11)/log9)`

Although I can get the length of a string (tokens) in Python:

```
 string = ['the', 'the', 'the', 'a', 'a', 'over', 'love', 'one', 'tree']
 len(string)
 9
```

And the number of types:

```
len(set(string))
6
```

I am not entirely sure how can I calculate this formula in Python. 
Thanks.

Source: Dale, Moisl, and Somers (p.551). "Handbook of Natural Language Processing" (2000). https://books.google.at/books?id=VoOLvxyX0BUC&pg=PA551&lpg=PA551&dq=entropy+vocabulary+richness&source=bl&ots=wucWFF1Rn_&sig=Hms1qwhXlcOaPEXI84eDqxsTEdo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAmoVChMIjvvQnvPVxwIVhJ5yCh35ZAb_#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/13271/shannons-entropy-as-a-measure-of-vocabulary-richness

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the Sigma, you could do this:

```
def calculateEntropy(freqDict,total):
    entropy=0
    nbElements=0
    for element in freqDict:
        p=float(freqDict[element])/total
        entropy-=p*math.log(p,2)
        nbElements+=1
    if nbElements==total:
        return entropy
    else:
        return calculateEntropy(freqDict,nbElements)
```

To get the tokens frequencies, you can use a simple dict with tokens as key and occurrences as values. To get your complete formula, you would still have to get `100*entropy/math.log(nbElements,2)`